# Warning: Undefined array key "city" in /my-api.php on line 15

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect an API using a php script to a phpmyadmin SQl table, but it keep's giving this error. I'm confused on where to fix it. It is the line in bold, and the issue is the with city column as the error is telling me. I'm using PHPmyadmin.

For it to get the values from the API and load them into the SQl table.

```
}

// Execute SQL query
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM weather
    WHERE city = '{$_GET['city']}' //line 15
    AND weather_when >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND)
    ORDER BY weather_when DESC limit 1";

$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);

// Error ?
if($result == false) {
    echo("<h4>SQL error description: " . $mysqli -> error . "</h4>");
}

// No data? Import fresh data and run query again!
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    include('data-import.php');
    $result = $mysqli -> query($sql); // Run query again after import
}


// Get data, convert to JSON and print
$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
print json_encode($row);

// Free result set and close connection
$result -> free_result();
$mysqli -> close();

?>
```

Comment: First you need to parametrize your query:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/ba-p/383483   Second doing it that way you are not sure what is going into the city column, you may have bad/different data than expected.  I would step through or write the city to console or something to see what is actually in there.

Comment: `$_GET` does not contain the array key `city`. Double-check what `$_GET` contains, and check to see if it exists before you try to use it.

Comment: You've tagged sql-server as your database, but you have decidedly non-tsql syntax in there. Are you sure you're about the database engine you're using? `date_sub` appears tobe mysql syntax.

Comment: By the way, PHPMyAdmin is only a GUI interface to a database, it is not the database itself. The database would be MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, SQLServer, etc, but PHPMyAdmin only supports MySQL and MariaDB